# How to upload Lambda output to S3 in an AWS Step Function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to use an AWS Step Function task (S3:putObject) to upload a CSV. The contents of the CSV are from a lambda in a previous task:

```
import { logger } from "./Logger";
import { json2csv } from "json-2-csv";

export const generateFileHandler = async (event: any) => {
  const fileDetails = event.detail.Message[0];

  const csv = await json2csv([fileDetails]);

  return { csv };
};

export const handler = middify(generateFileHandler);
```

```
 "Put Comms File": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Body.$": "$.csv",
        "Bucket": "${bucket_name}",
        "Key": "file.csv"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:putObject"
    },
```

It is uploading the file fine, but it's wrapping it in quotes. Further to this, it's ignoring \n, and having the whole csv on one line. I've tried converting it to a Buffer, but it just uploads the raw buffer object data as a string. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you checked the raw value of `csv` before going onto the Step Function task? This seems to be related to your Lambda and not the Step Function.

Comment: I assume @ErmiyaEskandary is correct. I think csv is already quoted as soon as it leaves your lambda function

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this SDK integration is simply broken. I've tried a lot of the intrinsic functions and such that are provided and it always wraps the content sent to s3 in quotes no matter what.